# How to fix 'column ambiguously defined' in oracle Join

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Following is my code snappiest. i don`t know why i am getting this issue. please assist me on this.

```
select cp.AMOUNT from customer_payee_transactions cp

LEFT OUTER JOIN merchant_transactions mt ON (cp.merchant_transaction_id = 
mt.merchant_transaction_id)

WHERE AMOUNT > 500 AND MODIFIED_DATETIME 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('27/01/2019 22:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
AND TO_DATE('27/01/2019 23:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss');
```

please help me on this.
Thank you.

Comment: Just use `table alias` in all of your columns!

Comment: What error you got ? edit the question & post it.

Comment: error is 'column ambiguously defined'

Comment: It's good programming practice to qualify all columns when more than one table is involved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `cp` before `AMOUNT` and `MODIFIED_DATETIME` columns as you've defined alias name for your table

```
select cp.AMOUNT 
from customer_payee_transactions cp LEFT OUTER JOIN merchant_transactions mt 
ON cp.merchant_transaction_id = mt.merchant_transaction_id
WHERE cp.AMOUNT > 500 AND cp.MODIFIED_DATETIME 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('27/01/2019 22:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
AND TO_DATE('27/01/2019 23:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss');
```

Comment: Same issue appears as it is.

Answer (score 1):

you need table alias name.column name

```
select cp.AMOUNT from customer_payee_transactions cp    
LEFT OUTER JOIN merchant_transactions mt ON (cp.merchant_transaction_id = 
mt.merchant_transaction_id)

WHERE cp.AMOUNT > 500 AND cp.MODIFIED_DATETIME 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('27/01/2019 22:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
AND TO_DATE('27/01/2019 23:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss');
```

Put also table alias name before `MODIFIED_DATETIME` this column

Comment: @L.Anush Because all 2 tables have column `MODIFIED_DATETIME`, and optimizer didn't know this column you want to compare date is from which table!

Comment: No i mistakenly forget alias on MODIFIED_DATETIME. sorry this works